# Escaping user data for redis, needed?

Tags: c++, redis, hiredis, redisjson

While using https://github.com/sewenew/redis-plus-plus as library for talking to redis, the following question came up.
How would you escape user send data, which should be saved as a value of e.g. a json object (**in order to not allow redis command injection**)?

```
json.set doc $ '{"key": "value"}'
```

The user could send:

```
val\"ue
```

as a new value for `key`.

I'm using the raw command for json.set in redis-plus-plus and had to pass it like this in order to get processed correctly by redis (value below would be the string `val"ue`):

```
m_pDb->jsonSet(key, "$.key", "\"" + value + "\"");
```

which calls this funtion:

```
void result(const std::vector<std::string>& cmd)
{
    auto val = m_pRedis->command(cmd.cbegin(), cmd.cend());
```

`ue` could now be interpreted as further redis command.
If I'm not wrong the command would at the end be like this:

```
json.set doc $.key "val"ue"
```

The point is, it should not be possible to "escape" out of the value and cause an parser error or whatever.

Is `value` passed wrong? Is there some build in escaping?
Should every possible injection escaped by the developer?

Comment: Does your project have a dependency on Boost? If so, we can take advantage of it to do the lifting for you here. If not, then it's up to you whether you want to add such a heavy dependency to do it.

Comment: No Boost, only Qt, what would you suggest doing with Boost?

Comment: I would consider using a client with better serialization support. For example, Aedis supports serialization of your own data types as shown in this example https://github.com/mzimbres/aedis/blob/562075230f99a46118557d0f518816a3a0bf0e5e/examples/serialization.cpp. Detailed documentation can be found here https://github.com/mzimbres/aedis.